# SQL Stored Procedures Call vs Multiple RecordSets

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, asp-classic

Im work with Classic ASP and all my pages do multiples calls (stored procedures) to database to construct the page (reports, forms...).
Is it better to do 1 call with multiple recordset or do what Im doing (multiple calls)?

I know, maybe, there is something better with another languages (PHP, C#...), but my app was built entirely in Classic ASP.

Tks

Comment: A call is an extra round trip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, there is a case for both ways.

To optimize for amount of total work done, as Blam said, you should do one big call to reduce the round trip time. Not only for network latency, but also for all the network overhead of putting together packets and handling sockets.

However, this would mean that your page gets no data until *all* database accesses are done. So to improve response time, you may want to consider doing a pipeline where there are some database calls, but you are also processing some of the database results while other calls are made. This is a fairly unusual case since most of the time, processing is fairly light.

A common reason to break up the stored procedure is for reuse. If you have one big stored procedure, then to reuse any part of the stored procedure, you have to reuse *all* of it. (Unless you do messy branches and conditions inside your stored procedure that probably hurt performance due to query plan optimizations.) If you have multiple pages that can share some of the code, you probably want to break it up.

In a typical web farm, the database and the page servers are fairly close together so that network latency is not too bad. I profiled some of our production loads, and there are several places where we make multiple database calls serially, taking less than 1 ms for 10 database calls.

If your database network latency is significant, it may be worth it to do database calls in parallel. This way, you can break your stored procedure up for code reuse and not worry about network latency.

As a general rule, make your code clean and pretty without worrying about performance. Throw more hardware at the problem until you can't make it faster by paying more money. Typically, hardware is a lot cheaper than developers.